# How can I authenticate with google cloud in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-automl

I'm trying to use google automl object detection in a Unity project.

Here is the google curl command example:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/models/model-id:predict \
  -d '{
        "payload" : {
          "image": {
            "imageBytes" : "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ … "
          },
        }
      }'
```

After some googling, I start to create a `UnityWebRequest` to test response:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

        var postUrl = "https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/1043345783500/locations/us-central1/models/IOD1798528344157847552:predict";

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(postUrl, form))
        {
            www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", @"Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)");

            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else if (www.isDone)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
            }

        }
```

So the response from google is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

I understand that, I am not unauthenticated but couldn't understand how I can authenticate. Do I have to make an authentication request? How? Do I have to post something to get an access token? Then where should I send it?

I downloaded some credentials from google server but I really don't have any idea how to use it...

Comment: `$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)` looks like a command in the terminal which thanks to the `"` will be replaced by the result of that command ... in Unity you have `@".."` so this string is sent as it is .. which makes no sense ... you have to get a valid access token here.

Comment: @derHugo what I was trying is sending cUrl commands via c#. I just want to copy `-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \ ` command as `www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", @"Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)");`

Do you have an idea what should I do exactly?

Comment: as said `$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)` is a command in the terminal which generates an output ... let's say e.g. something like `234987234dfkjdfg87` and is replaced and submitted as the actual header value ... somehow you have to do the same in Unity and first reuest a valid auth token and submit that token not the `$(...)` command